# How does one define projective dimension in terms of the Ext functor?

Tags: homological-algebra

Would it be 
$pd_{R}M:=sup\lbrace i\vert Ext^{i}_{R}(M,N)\neq 0:N$ is an $R$-module$\rbrace$ or $pd_{R}M:=sup\lbrace i\vert Ext^{i}_{R}(M,N):N\neq 0$ is a free $R$-module$\rbrace$
or something else entirely?

Comment: My mistake, I have edited what I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the following equivalence to establish the definition:

> $\text{Ext}_R^{n}(M,N) = 0$ for all $N$ iff $\text{pd}_R M < n$

This is probably in any textbook discussing homological dimensions, also conveniently [in these notes](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/ComAlg/ComAlg7.pdf).

From here, a definition easily pops out:

> **definition**:  $\text{pd}_R M = \inf\big\{n  \mid \text{Ext}_R^{n+1}(M,N) =0 \text{ for all $N$}\big\}  = \sup\big\{n  \mid \text{Ext}_R^{n}(M,N) \not=0 \text{ for some $N$}\big\}$

Comment: Can we not write this in the form of a supremum at all?

Comment: Yes you certainly can, and the translation between the inf and sup definitions is immediate. Edited.